# in app purchase localization unsupported languages

Tags: ios, localization, in-app-purchase

How can I add **Display Name** and **Description** with unsupported language like Arabic in-app-purchase ?

Comment: please clarify more to your point

Comment: When you add new in-app-purchase you specify price, id and screen shot in addition to Display Name and Description in one of few supported languages 
How can I add the display name and description with unsupported language ?

Comment: Sorry, Buddy You cannot add Display Name and Description with unsupported language for in-app-purchase as Apple haven't given access for languages other than defined language..